# How to have a one-to-one relation to either one of two other tables

Tags: database-design

Suppose I have three tables

- `orders`  table, fields: name, address, country, paid, shipped, amount
- `paypal` payment table, fields: order_id
- `stripe` payment table, fields: customer_id, cvc_valid, address_valid, zip_valid

Each order should be associated with only one payment table, `paypal` or `stripe`

Question is: How do I associate an Order with its payment when it is possible that the payment is either in the Paypal table or in the Stripe table?

I thought of adding an enum field to the Orders table to decide whether to look up the payment in the Paypal table or to look up in the Stripe table. Are there better methods than this?

I would like to use either MariaDB, MySQL, or SQLite.

Answer (score 2):

There are several options:

1. Combine `Paypal` and `Stripe` tables into a single `Payment` table, with fields to hold either type of payment;
2. Have both a `paypal_id` and a `stripe_id` in the `Order` table; use a condition on the table to ensure that at least one of them is NULL.
3. Have a single Payment_ID with a flag to indicate whether it's an id from `Paypal` or `Stripe` as you propose.

The first two options allow for the payment ID(s) to be foreign keys to the payment table(s), the third does not.

I would lean towards a single table with all payment data, but that may be a personal preference. Which of the first two options is better would depend on whether there are any common columns between `Paypal` and `Stripe`, and just how large the distinct columns are.

UPDATE: joanolo's answer lays out how to actually implement my option 2; take a look!

Answer (score 2):

In an SQL-compliant database you could have something like the following settings:

```
 CREATE TABLE paypal
 (
     paypal_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
     paypal_info text
 ) ;

 CREATE TABLE stripe
 (
     stripe_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
     stripe_info text
 ) ;

 CREATE TABLE orders
 (
     order_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
     order_info text,

     paypal_id integer REFERENCES paypal(paypal_id),
     stripe_id integer REFERENCES stripe(stripe_id),

     -- Make sure one and only one of (paypal_id, stripe_id) is not null
     CONSTRAINT must_have_paypal_or_stripe_but_not_both
     CHECK (    paypal_id IS NULL     AND stripe_id IS NOT NULL
             OR paypal_id IS NOT NULL AND stripe_id IS NULL )
 ) ;


 -- Make two payments, one paypal, one stripe
 INSERT INTO paypal (paypal_id, paypal_info) VALUES (1,    'paypal 1');
 INSERT INTO stripe (stripe_id, stripe_info) VALUES (1001, 'stripe 1');
```

Now, two examples of "legal" orders:

```
 -- We insert a legal order
 INSERT INTO orders (order_id, order_info, paypal_id) 
             VALUES (1, 'Order we payed with paypal', 1);

 -- And another one
 INSERT INTO orders (order_id, order_info, stripe_id) 
             VALUES (2, 'Order we payed with stripe', 1001);
```

And now, two illegal ones:

```
 -- An illegal one
 INSERT INTO orders (order_id, order_info) 
    VALUES (1, 'Order without paypal_id or stripe_id');
```

> ERROR:  new row for relation "orders" violates check constraint "must_have_paypal_or_stripe_but_not_both"
>   DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, Order without paypal_id or stripe_id, null, null).

```
 -- And another illegal one
 INSERT INTO orders (order_id, order_info, paypal_id, stripe_id) 
   VALUES (1, 'Order with both paypal_id or stripe_id', 1, 1001);
```

> ERROR:  new row for relation "orders" violates check constraint "must_have_paypal_or_stripe_but_not_both"
>   DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, Order with both paypal_id or stripe_id, 1, 1001).

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=35f2f69f69fbcf99a1040a7be267adcd)*

Answer (score 1):

Your question sounds like a classic case of type and subtypes (or class and subclasses).  Paypal and Stripe are both subclasses of a superclass that I'll call Payment.  There is a tag, [subtypes](/questions/tagged/subtypes), that has information about similar cases.

Briefly, there are several techniques for modeling this situation, and for representing the model in SQL tables.  In ER modeling, this situation is called "generalization/specialization" and there are numerous good articles on the web under those buzzwords.  In table design, there are two patterns that have been used enough to have been given a name.  They are called single table inheritance and class table inheritance.

In single table inheritance, there is one table for the superclass, and it contains columns for the common data and for all the subclasses.  You'll need an extra column to indicate the subtype (subclass) of each instance.  Any data that does not pertain to a given instance is left NULL.  This is the simplest option, and it works well in many cases, especially small scale.  The NULLs take up a little room and slow down access to the table, but not by very much.

This is very much like option 1 in the answer from RDFozz

In class table inheritance there is one table for the superclass and one table for each subclass.  In your case, this would mean a Payment, Paypal, and Stripe.  The subclass tables often do not have a separate id field.  instead, there is a foreign key that references the superclass tables and also uniquely identifies the entry in the subclass table.  So it can be used as the primary key in the subclass table as well as being a foreign key.  This has advantages when you go to join the superclass table with one of the subclass tables.

Class table inheritance has fewer NULLS but more joins.  It sometimes works out better, especially when there is little common superclass data, as in your case.